# Application class for static variables and MultiDex applications

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-multidex

This guide here tell you how to create an Application class:

http://www.intridea.com/blog/2011/5/24/how-to-use-application-object-of-android

It mentions that you need to define the name of your Application class in your manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="MyApplication">
```

I think Application class are useful to hold static variables / objects like for example, GoogleApiClient so that you do not have to reconnect with Google each time your activity ends, instead if you put it in your application class, you will only need to connect once when your app starts up and disconnect when it closes.

I have a multidex app: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Multidex apps requires me to also give a constant name of `"android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` to the application in the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

If I have to give `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"` as the application name, I cannot also give `android:name="MyApplication"`. As far as I know, an application cannot have two names.

Is it possible to have both multidex and a custom application class in an app?

Comment: Did you try reading the part of 'Avoiding the 65K Limit' in the multidex page? Because if you havent, you should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think Application class are useful to hold static variables / objects

If they are `static`, then `Application` is not holding them.

> Is it possible to have both multidex and a custom application class in an app?

According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/multidex/MultiDexApplication.html), you can either have your class extend `MultiDexApplication` or have it override `attachBaseContext()` and call `MultiDex.install(this)` instead of needing `MultiDexApplication`.

Comment: Thanks, I think I might not have been clear in my question but what I meant is if they are in the application class, the objects would not be garbage collected as frequently as the activity class and making the objects static would allow all the classes to be able to access these objects. I was not aware that I can extend multidex application and will try that. Thanks!